# Filter from a table Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two tables: Restaurant and Meal

`restaurant has_many meals` and `meal belongs_to restaurant`.
Hence each meal has a `restaurant_id` column.

I have a `@meals_search` variable in my controller that is a list of meals from a search of a user in a search bar.

I want to display the restaurants corresponding to the `@meals_search.restaurant_id` but so far I can't find the right ActiveRecord query.

For example, if `@meals_search.pluck(:restaurant_id)` is equal to [1,7,44,53], then I want to create a `@restaurants` variable that stores restaurants with id 1,7, 44 and 53.

I populate the @meals_search variable like this:

meals_controller.rb

`@meals_search = @meals.search(params[:search])`

model.meal.rb

```
  belongs_to :restaurant

def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You want to get all meals which have specified restaurant_id? Am I right?

Comment: Nope, I want all restaurants that have an id corresponding to restaurant_id from the @meals_search variable. I edit the post to make it a bit clearer :)

Comment: Can you show how you are populating the `@meals_search` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you simply need to do this:

```
@restaurants = Restaurant.where(id: @meals_search.pluck(:restaurant_id))
```

This uses ActiveRecord [subset conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions).

The above query translates to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Restaurant WHERE (restaurant.in IN (1,3,5))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like this?

```
@restaurants = Restaurant.where(id: @meals_search.pluck(:restaurant_id))
```

Comment: that works ! @Marek Lipka was a little faster than you but thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `map` insted of `pluck`

```
@restaurants = Restaurant.where(id: @meals_search.map {|m| m.restaurant_id})
```

Comment: I don't think that works, as restaurants and meals do not have the same ids. e.g. meal 22 does not correspond to restaurant 22

Comment: It was a typo. Thanks